# Quartz.Net change properties of JobDetail / JobKey

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

While migrating Quartz.net from version 1.0.x I've come across the problem of "missing setters" for various properties of JobDetails and JobKeys.

While it was possible to set for example the "Group" of a JobKey or the "JobDataMap" of the JobDetail or the property "Durable" in version 1.0.x, it isn't possible anymore in version 2.3.2 because the setters are missing

```
jobDetail.Key.Group = task.GroupName + JobDefinitions.QuartzDefinitions.GroupNamesExtensions.Rejected;
jobDetail.JobDataMap = new JobDataMap(DictionaryUtils.ConvertToDictionary(task.JobDetails));
```

Is there another possibility to change these properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Quartz.Net 2 you're kind of expected to go through the [JobBuilder](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/?topic=html/c16b6f32-93c4-9e2d-d81c-a716f5f0babc.htm) for these kinds of things.

Of particular interest for the above are the UsingJobData methods and the WithIdentity methods.